# J2EE JSP-0008 Unable to dispatch JSP page

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, oc4j

I'm building a dynamic web application in Eclipse using Struts2 and OC4J 10.1.3.3.0. I'm using JDK and JRE 5 everywhere, and OC4J runs perfect when started from the command line.

The problem comes when I try to deploy the project from Eclipse, it throws this error when trying to render the JSP:

> 2010-07-16 11:21:20.962 NOTIFICATION 
>   J2EE JSP-0008 Unable to dispatch JSP page:
>   oracle.jsp.provider.JspCompileException:
>
> #### Compile Errors :D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\application-deployments\Login2\Login2\persistence_pages\_Login.java
>
> at
>   oracle.jsp.app.JspJavacCompiler.compile(JspJavacCompiler.java:304)
>     at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.attemptCompilePage(JspPageCompiler.java:731)
>     at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.compileBothModes(JspPageCompiler.java:456)
>     at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.compilePage(JspPageCompiler.java:413)
>     at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageInfo.compileAndLoad(JspPageInfo.java:705)
>     at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.compileAndServe(JspPageTable.java:694)
>     at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:414)
>     at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:594)
>     at
>   oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:518)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
>     at
>   com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:389)
>     at
>   com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:623)
>     at
>   com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:370)
>     at
>   com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:871)
>     at
>   com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:453)
>     at
>   com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:221)
>     at
>   com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:122)
>     at
>   com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:111)
>     at
>   oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
>     at
>   oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:239)
>     at
>   oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:34)
>     at
>   oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:880)
>     at
>   com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)

This is what eclipse shows when starting oc4j:

> 2010-07-16 13:24:39.987 NOTIFICATION Inicio de Application Deployer para Login2.
>   2010-07-16 13:24:39.988 NOTIFICATION Anular despliegue anterior
>   2010-07-16 13:24:39.990 NOTIFICATION Inicio de Application UnDeployer para Login2.
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.570 NOTIFICATION Eliminando todos los enlaces Web para la aplicación Login2 de todas las direcciones Web
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.652 NOTIFICATION Se ha terminado Application UnDeployer para Login2.
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.678 NOTIFICATION Inicio de la inicialización de D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2.ear...
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.680 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2.ear... 
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.680 NOTIFICATION Unjar D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2.ear in >D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.712 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2.ear
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.732 NOTIFICATION Auto-unpacking D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2\Login2.war... 
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.732 NOTIFICATION Unjar D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2\Login2.war in >D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2\Login2
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.808 NOTIFICATION Finished auto-unpacking D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2\Login2.war
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.810 NOTIFICATION Fin de la inicialización de D:\Java\contenedor\oc4j_extended_101330\j2ee\home\applications\Login2.ear...
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.811 NOTIFICATION Iniciando la aplicación: Login2
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.812 NOTIFICATION Inicializando ClassLoaders
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.812 NOTIFICATION Inicializando contenedor EJB
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.813 NOTIFICATION Cargando conectores
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.843 NOTIFICATION Iniciando los adaptadores de recursos
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.844 NOTIFICATION Inicializando sesiones de EJB
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.845 NOTIFICATION Confirmando ClassLoaders
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.846 NOTIFICATION Inicio de la inicialización de Login2...
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.862 NOTIFICATION Fin de la inicialización de Login2...
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.869 NOTIFICATION Aplicación iniciada: Login2
>   2010-07-16 13:24:40.887 NOTIFICATION Inicio de enlace de aplicaciones Web a la dirección default-web-site...
>   2010-07-16 13:24:41.177 NOTIFICATION Fin de enlace de aplicaciones Web a la dirección default-web-site...
>   2010-07-16 13:24:41.178 NOTIFICATION Se ha terminado Application Deployer para Login2. Hora de la Operación: 1193 msecs
>   16/07/2010 01:24:50 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
>   INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
>   16/07/2010 01:24:51 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
>   INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
>   16/07/2010 01:24:51 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
>   INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
>   16/07/2010 01:24:51 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
>   INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
>   16/07/2010 01:24:51 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
>   INFO: Loading global messages from ApplicationResources

The JSP is fine, it's just simple HTML and also runs fine with Tomcat. I don't understand what is happening here. Any ideas?

Comment: Please look a bit further in the logs for exceptions and root causes and update your question to include that information. Preferably, post **all** exceptions/errors/warnings/traces you see in the logs.

Comment: Well, there are compilation errors. Please post them as well.

Comment: There's no compile error, as I said it compiles and renders perfect with tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that when starting oc4j from Eclipse, oc4j has problems finding java at C:\Program Files (x86)\java.

It seems that "(" is a special character that eclipse or oc4j can´t parse well.

Moving java to C:\ and setting oc4j with this new path solves the problem.